# Qual a diferença entre autômatos e gramáticas?

Tags: autômatos

Estou estudando sobre compiladores e relacionando as linguagens de programação. Qual a diferença entre autômatos e gramáticas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Linguagens Formais

No estudo das [linguagens formais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_formal), uma *linguagem* é um conjunto de *strings* sobre um alfabeto. Uma *string* é uma sequência de letras obtidas de um dado alfabeto<sup>1</sup>.

nota: Normalmente se traduz string como "palavra" mas talvez "frase" fosse mais correto, já que espaços são uma letra como qualquer outra do ponto de vista de linguagens formais e "A B" é uma única string.

### Gramáticas

Uma gramática serve para descrever a estrutura de uma linguagem formal. Gramáticas consistem de uma série de regras que descrevem como formar palavras da linguagem. Por exemplo, uma das gramáticas que descreve a linguagem das strings de parênteses bem balanceados é a seguinte gramática:

```
regra inicial: S
regras de geração: 
S -> ()     // Um par de parênteses é bem balanceado
S -> ( S )  // Uma string balanceada cercada de parênteses é bem balanceada
S -> S S    // Duas strings balanceadas em sequência são bem balanceadas.
```

Gramáticas podem ser usadas para gerar strings mas a operação mais interessante é, dado uma string, obter uma árvore de sintaxe que descreve a estrutura da string em relação à gramática. Por exemplo, na linguagem de expressões aritméticas, a string "1 + 2 * 3" vai ser traduzida na seguinte árvore:

```
  soma
  /  \
1   produto
      /  \
    2     3
```

É sobre essas árvores de sintaxe que o compilador de nossa linguagem de programação ou o avaliador de expressões da nossa calculadora vai operar. É algo bem mais estruturado que que um texto achatado.

Existem várias perguntas que podemos fazer sobre gramáticas:

- A gramática é ambigua? Existe alguma string que pode ser derivada usando duas árvores de derivação diferentes ou toda string tem uma derivação única? Por exemplo, se não usarmos regras de precedência para os operadores, em `1 + 2 * 3` é ambíguo se a soma ou a multiplicação vem primeiro.
- A gramática é regular? A gramática é livre de contexto? A gramática é recursiva à esquerda? Quanto mais geral for a gramática mais geral é a linguagem que ela pode descrever mas ao mesmo temo mais complexo e custoso será o algoritmo para fazer o parsing.

### Autômatos

Autômatos são máquinas de estado que recebem uma palavra e retornam SIM ou NÂO no final. No contexto de linguagens formais, autômatos são associados à linguagem das strings que eles aceitam com um SIM.

Autômatos são classificados com o poder computacional que eles podem usar: A memória disponível é finita, em pilha, ilimitada...? O processamento é determinístico ou não determinístico (paralelo)?

Alguns exemplos de perguntas que podemos fazer sobre autômatos:

- Dois autômatos reconhecem a mesma linguagem?
- Podemos diminuir o número de estados de um autômato sem alterar a linguagem reconhecida?
- O que acontece se decidirmos combinar dois autômatos?
- Qual é a diferença em termos de linguagens reconhecíveis de autômatos determinísticos e não determinísticos, com mais ou menos memória? E em termos de custo de execução e número de estados necessários?

### Classificação de gramáticas vs autômatos. Onde se encaixam os compiladores?

Uma classificação bastante interessante é a [hierarquia de Chomsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy), que associa algumas importantes classes de linguagens formais com quais tipos de gramáticas são capazes de gerar essas linguagens e quais autômatos podem ser  usados para reconhecê-las:

```
       | Linguagens                 | Automato                | Regras de produção da gramática
Tipo 0 | Recursivamente enumeráveis | Máquina de Turing       | (sem restrições)
Tipo 1 | Sensíveis ao contexto      | MT linearmente limitada | a X b -> c Y d
Tipo 2 | Livres de contexto         | Pilha ñ determinístico  | X -> a Y b
Tipo 3 | Regulares                  | Finito                  | X -> a Y
```

Dessa lista, o mais importante para um compilador são as gramáticas livres de contexto e os autômatos finitos.

As gramáticas livres de contexto são as que você normalmente vai usar para descrever a sua linguagem de programação, uma vez que linguagens de programação precisam ser processadas de forma eficiente e a ausência de efeitos de contexto leva a árvores de sintaxe mais previsíveis. Alem de evitar ambiguidades, você também vai ter que prestar atenção se a sua gramática é compativel com o tipo de parser que você vai usar. Se você for escrever um parser top down, (recursivo, escritpa mão), sua gramática vai precisar ser uma gramática LL, sem recursão à esquerda. Já se você for usar um parser bottom up- como o yacc ou bison, a sua gramática pode ser uma gramática LR, que tem menos restrições.

Quanto aos autômatos, os que você vai passar mais tempo estudando são os autômatos finitos. Eles são usados para reconhecer expressões regulares, que são usadas extensivamente no lexer, que é o primeiro passo da compilação.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, esclareceu minha dúvida, muito obrigado!