# O que é um autômato?

Tags: terminologia, autômatos

Por várias vezes eu ouço discussões sobre autômatos, seja no *chat* ou em perguntas/respostas. Entretanto eu particularmente não sei o que é um autômato, não tenho nem ideia para falar a verdade. Quando aparece aquelas imagens então, pra mim é "alienes".

Vejo vários "tipos de autômatos", como finito determinístico, finito, celular entre outros.

- O que é um autômato?
- O que fazem os autômatos? Para que servem?
- Onde vivem os autômatos?

Comment: Relacionado: [O que é um autômato celular?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/224851/28595)

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre autômatos e gramáticas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28297/91)

Comment: É uma boa pergunta, mas é ampla para ... nossa, envolve muita coisa

Comment: Não quer saber o que eles comem ou como eles se reproduzem? :D

Comment: @Maniero eles comem letras e vivem em espaços imaginários! E a reprodução é por geração espontânea, eles não são sujeitas à evolução

Comment: Embora seja antiga, essa pergunta na verdade não tem nada a ver com programação, dentro do escopo do site.

Comment: Discordo totalmente de sua opinião. Se você leu a completa resposta do @JeffersonQuesado **e** entendeu, você deve ter percebido a participação direta de um autômato ao escopo de programação, definido para este site.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Não quer saber o que eles [autômatos] comem ou como eles se reproduzem?
> Maniero Junior, Antonio, [2017](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260864/o-que-%c3%a9-um-aut%c3%b4mato#comment534836_260864)

Autômatos comem letras/tokens discretos, vivendo em espaços matemáticos. A priori, se a matemática não existir, eles estão no mundo imaginário. Se a matemática existir, então eles estão no plano das ideias.

Eles se reproduzem por geração espontânea, não possuem código genético. Devido a não terem hereditariedade, eles não estão sujeitos a evolução

Existem entidades que possuem código genético e desse código genético produzem autômatos. Nesse sentido, o paralelo "autômato" com a biologia seria mais parecido com "proteínas".

---

## O que é um autômato?

Autômato, como dito acima, é uma entidade matemática. A etimologia da palavra vem desde a época das [máquinas analógicas auto-operadas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automaton). Existem sistemas auto-operados desde o período helenístico, alguns até anteriores a isso. A única coisa que precisa para manter esses sistemas funcionando é uma fonte de energia.

Um relógio de corda é um mecanismo auto-operado. A única coisa que você precisa fornecer a ele é energia. Você fornece essa energia "dando corda", então esse energia fica armazenada em um capacitor através de energia elástica e fica abastecendo o mecanismo conforme a energia vai sendo necessária.

Outro exemplo de autômato de corda é esse aqui:

[image: autômato atirando uma flecha]

Um autômato que ficou conhecido no cinema foi [A invenção de Hugo Cabret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Cabret), que desenha cenas de filmes clássicos.

Matematicamente, os autômatos não tem a limitação física de necessitar de energia para operar, pois no mundo matemático não há problemas com conservação e gasto de energia. Eles simplesmente são "mecanismos" auto-operados que funcionam em cima de uma *entrada*.

De maneira típica, a *entrada* na qual eles trabalham é constituída de células discreta, cada célula dessa contendo um pedaço de informação. Muitas vezes essa informação é representada por um número ou uma letra. O mais correto seria chamar de **símbolo de informação**, ou ***token* de informação**.

Como a entrada é fornecida através de símbolos?, como o autômato consegue identificar onde começa e onde termina a informação e onde começa outra?

O modo como essa informação é passada ao autômato varia. Normalmente é uma fita semi-infinita. Podem ser múltiplas fitas semi-infinitas, ou mesmo infinitas em ambas as direções. Mas pode ser um plano. Ou um espaço tridimensional. Ou até mesmo `n`-dimensional. Seja lá como for, o autômato tem uma (ou mais) "cabeça" de onde ele lê a informação. Semelhante ao HD magnético, que tem cabeça de leitura/escrita de informações, assim o autômato percorre interage com sua entrada.

> Uma fita semi-infinita tem o mesmo poder computacional que uma fita infinita para ambos os lados. Imagine uma situação hipotética em que uma Máquina de Turing encontra-se no começo dos dados da fita e "precisa" escrever algo no começo da fita. Em uma fita infinita ele só precisaria ir uma posição a mais para a esquerda e, então, escrever o que se necessita.
>
> Numa fita semi-infinita, entretanto, isso não é possível. Não existe mais nada "à esquerda" do começo dos dados. O que poderia ser feito nesse caso seria um deslocamento de TODOS os dados da fita uma posição para a direita, escrevendo o símbolo desejado no mais a esquerda possível. Esse problema é uma instância do [Hotel de Hilbert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel), onde é necessário acomodar mais um hóspede e ele é acomodado à esquerda. Se for necessário, é possível acomodar mais do que um hóspede, deslocando quem já está hospedado `n` quartos para a direita.

Tem alguns modelos matemáticos que a Máquina de Turing (o mais poderoso dos autômatos) tem 3 fitas semi-infinitas:

1. **fita de leitura**, onde a cabeça só pode ler e só pode ir para frente; sem escritas ou *back-tracking*
2. **fita de escrita**, onde a cabeça só pode escrever e ir para frente; sem leituras ou *back-tracking*
3. **fita de trabalho**, onde a cabeça se movimenta a vontade e onde ocorre a computação; a memória RAM do computador seria essa "fita de trabalho"

Esse modelo matemático oferece tanto poder computacional que uma Máquina de Turing com apenas uma única fita semi-infinita, onde ele pode realizar escritas e leituras ilimitadamente e não tem limitação da direção do movimento da cabeça. A vantagem do modelo que separa em 3 fitas é que algumas propriedades ficam mais fáceis de serem demonstradas.

## O que fazem os autômatos? Para que servem?

Os autômatos são entidade que vão ler as informações contidas na cabeça de leitura, possivelmente alterar alguma informação através da cabeça de escrita e movimentar as cabeças em direções arbitrárias.

Então, eles leem e escrevem. Eles "só" fazem isso. Normalmente eles possuem estado interno que indicam o que fazer a seguir.

Para representar um autômato, normalmente fazem um desenho através de um grafo contendo as seguintes informações:

1. os estados (vértices)
2. as transações (arestas)
3. o que é necessário para a transação ocorrer (rótulo das arestas)

Dependendo do autômato, a informação para colocar no rótulo pode variar. Por exemplo, em autômatos finitos (entrada em fita finita, cabeça apenas de leitura, toda leitura movimenta a cabeça uma posição para a esquerda), só é necessário colocar qual a informação que precisa ser lida para indicar qual a mudança de estado que vai ocorrer. Veja abaixo:

[image: exemplo de autômato finito]

Em autômatos de pilha, você tem a entrada igual a do autômato finito e, também, possui uma pilha de onde você pode ler e escrever elementos nela (mas apenas na última posição). Toda leitura da pilha implica em, necessariamente, remover o último elemento do topo; se quiser manter a pilha intacta após uma leitura, você deve escrever novamente esse elemento na pilha. Você também pode não ler a pilha. Assim como pode escrever na pilha sem consumir nada. Veja abaixo:

[image: exemplo de autômato de pilha]

Olhe para a primeira transação: `-,-/S`. Isso indica 3 coisas:

1. o traço `-` antes da vírgula indica que ele simplesmente ignorou a entrada, então essa transação ocorre sem leituras
2. `-/S` indica que nada é lido da pilha através do `-` antes da barra; e
3. o símbolo `S` é inserido em seu topo

Olhe para a segunda transação, `-,S/-`:

1. novamente, ignora a entrada com o traço
2. é necessário ter `S` no topo da pilha, símbolo esse que, por ter sido lido, será sacado fora
3. o traço após a barra em `S/-` indica que não é inserido nada na pilha

Só mais uma transação, `a,S/SBB`:

1. é necessário ler `a` da entrada
2. é necessário ter `S` no topo da pilha
3. vai ser escrito `SBB`, nessa ordem, então o próximo topo da pilha é `S`, então `B`, e então terá mais um `B`.

Em Máquinas de Turing de uma fita, como a cabeça se move livremente, você precisa indicar em cada transação:

1. o símbolo lido (ou algo para indicar que tanto faz)
2. o símbolo escrito (ou algo para indicar que não vai escrever)
3. a direção da leitura

No final, o autômato vai fazer uma computação em cima dessas informações. Sem precisar de estímulo externo, apenas fornecendo a ele a entrada. Essa computação pode ser para produzir um novo valor (quando o retorno está contido em alguma fita/plano/hiperplano de escrita) ou então simplesmente para tomar uma decisão; no caso da decisão, o estado interno em que o autômato finaliza a computação indica se aceitou ou recusou a entrada. Voltando ao primeiro autômato (o autômato finito):

[image: exemplo de autômato finito]

Os seguintes estados são de aceitação da entrada:

1. `q0`
2. `qb1`
3. `qb2`
4. `qa`

O seguinte estado indica recusa da entrada:

1. `damnation`

Esse autômato reconhece todas as palavras que não contenham a substring `bbab`. Então, não importa qual seja sua entrada, se ela contiver `bbab` em algum lugar, ela vai parar no estado `damnation` e sua palavra será recusada ao terminar a leitura. Tente executar esse autômato na mão, você aprenderá muito com ele.

## Onde vivem os autômatos?

Vive na matemática e na cabeça dos nerds =D

---

## Classificação de autômatos

Existem algumas maneiras de classificar os autômatos. Uma delas é diferenciar um autômato de processamento/computação, onde algo relevante será escrito na fita de saída, dos autômatos de decisão, onde nada precisa ser escrito e só se interessa se o seu estado final é um estado de aceitação ou não.

Mas eu prefiro ordená-los pelo seu poder computacional (e características secundárias de seu funcionamento).

### Máquina de estados finito determinística

Também conhecido como **autômato finito determinístico**, AFD

Esses autômatos são capazes de reconhecer qualquer gramática regular. Não importa o quão complicada ela seja, esse autômato a reconhecerá.

Expressões regulares (sem *look ahead* e outras coisas estranhas) são descritas por gramáticas regulares, então cada expressão regular terá seu autômato finito determinístico.

Eles são caracterizados por:

- qualquer leitura avança a fita de leitura, **sempre**
- avançar (na leitura) sempre, retroceder (na leitura) jamais
- não há fita de trabalho
- sabendo o estado atual e o caracter disponível na cabeça de leitura, eu **sempre** conheço o estado seguinte, e eu sei que só pode haver um
- só posso mudar de estado com leitura (sem transações lambda/vazias)

AFDs podem gerar saída sim. Se a escrita na fita de saída for determinada única e exclusivamente pelo estado de destino, então temos uma [máquina de Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine). Caso a transação disparada seja a responsável por produzir o símbolo na fita de saída, então temos uma [máquina de Mealy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine).

### Máquina de estado finito não determinística sem transações lambda

Também conhecido como autômato finito não determinístico sem transações lambda, AFN sem lambda.

A diferença deste autômato para o AFD é um relaxamento nas restrições do AFD.

> Restrição removida:
>
> - sabendo o estado atual e o caracter disponível na cabeça de leitura, eu **sempre** conheço o estado seguinte, e eu sei que só pode haver um

Ela é relaxada, permitindo que, para um mesmo símbolo de leitura, possam haver 2 ou mais destinos possíveis.

Computacionalmente, pode parecer que reconhece mais do que o AFD. Mas isso não é verdade, tudo que uma AFN sem lambda reconhece, há algum AFD que reconheça. Ou seja:

- ambos os autômatos possuem o mesmo poder computacional
- é possível obter um AFD a partir de um AFN

### Máquina de estados finito não determinística com transações lambda

Também conhecido como autômato finito não determinístico, AFN.

Esse autômato permite a existência de mudança de estado sem consumo de símbolos da fita de leitura. A essa mudança de estado sem consumir leitura damos o nome de "transação lambda".

AFNs podem ser reduzidos para AFDs, sempre. Ambos possuem o mesmo poder computacional.

> Mais tarde ponho:

- autômato de pilha
- autômato de fila
- autômato de duas pilhas
- máquina de Turing

Comment: Eu lembro dessas referencias :D

Answer (score -2):

Vamos lá, primeiramente, um autômato é uma máquina, no caso um robô que imita os movimentos de um ser humano, pode ser uma pessoa ou animal, outro ponto, para ser um autômato, ele não pode agir por si mesmo, ou seja, tomar decisões próprias, todas decisões são definidas automaticamente (instruções pré programadas). Segundo, o uso depende do tipo de autômato, mas no geral é executar ações pré determinadas, ou seja, fazer movimentos, ou falar e terceiro,  onde vivem os autômatos? Como dito, autômatos são máquinas, portanto "vivem" onde foram feitos para estar, por exemplo: Um boneco de parque que fala e estende a mão ao passar um pessoa em sua frente, este vive no parque, assim por diante.

Comment: Nessa pergunta eu pus um autômato que não imita um ser humano, um animal ou qualquer outra entidade vivente: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969; sua resposta está errada no contexto dessa pergunta. Principalmente se você olhar as perguntas relacionadas