# Por que uma Máquina de Turing com fita limitada não tem o mesmo poder computacional que um Autômato Finito?

Tags: teoria-da-computação, autômatos, linguagens-formais

Uma Máquina de Turing com Fita Limitada possui uma fita finita, um conjunto de estados finitos e alfabetos finitos, correto? Portanto, pode assumir um conjunto de estados finitos. Sendo assim, por que o seu poder computacional não é equivalente ao de um Autômato Finito?

Comment: Como você definiria um autômato finito que aceite a linguagem {0ⁿ1ⁿ| n>0}, supondo que *n* seja menor que a metade do tamanho da fita? Porém, se você considerar um autômato finito com 2 pilhas (A2P), a resposta é sim, eles tem o mesmo poder computacional.

Comment: @Gomiero, autômato de 2 pilhas tem o mesmo poder computacional que o autômato de fila, que por sua vez tem o mesmo poder computacional que uma MT.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Boa! Valeu! Tem razão, e tem uma lista enorme deles que eu não cheguei a estudar. Preciso renovar meus livros :-)

Comment: Tem uma resposta minha que eu queria expandir com alguns tipos mais significativos de autômatos https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260964/64969 . A demonstração que o autômato de 2 pilhas equivale ao de fila é simples, se reduz ao problema "escreva uma fila usando como base 2 pilhas". Agora, de autômato de fila para MT a demonstração é bem mais divertida e no momento eu não tenho nem a mínima ideia de como seguir.

Answer (score 4):

Vamos fazer um experimento mental? Vamos começar uma máquina de Turing, tranquilo?

Primeiro, vamos nos lembrar como que trabalha uma máquina de Turing? Ela é um conjunto de regras que, dado um símbolo na fita e o estado da MT, ele irá escrever um novo símbolo nessa posição da fita, irá mudar a posição de leitura e irá mudar de estado (pode mudar de estado para o mesmo estado). Isso é uma "transição", grossamente falando.

Tome por exemplo a seguinte situação. A fita estou representando por símbolos em minúsculas, o estado da máquina de Turing por uma letra maiúscula colocada à esquerda do símbolo que ela está lendo:

```
aaaVbbb
```

Se fizermos uma transição trocando `b` por `a` e indo para a esquerda mudando para o estado `A`, temos que ficaria desse jeito após disparar essa transição:

```
aaAaabb
```

Podemos falar que essa transição é:

```
V(b) ::= A, a, <=
```

onde a primeira posição da tupla de retorno é o novo estado, a segunda é o novo estado e a terceira posição da tupla é para onde mover a cabeça da máquina de Turing, só pode receber os valores `<=` (mexer a esquerda) e `=>` (mexer a direita).

Só para completar, um estado pode ser de aceitação ou não. Se parou em qualquer dos estados de aceitação, a máquina de Turing aceitou a entrada como válida. Caso contrário, ao chegar no final do processamento em um estado que não seja de aceitação, recusou a entrada.

Agora, vamos colocar algumas restrições nessa máquina de Turing? Vamos chamar de Autômato Capado. A primeira restrição que vamos fazer em Autômato Capado em relação à máquina de Turing é que ele só pode mexer para a direita. Ou seja:

```
S1(v1) ::= S2, v2, =>
```

Quaisquer que sejam S1, S2, v1 e v2.

Pronto, agora temos que, necessariamente, Autômato Capado irá a cada passo consumir uma letra da entrada e sempre se encaminhar para o final da entrada. Podemos colocar uma regra adicional também: `v1` precisa ser parte do alfabeto de entrada. Se não for do alfabeto de entrada (por exemplo, célula vazia à direita da entrada na fita de trabalho infinita), então essa transição não pode estar em Autômato Capado.

Como o autômato nunca irá retornar na fita, então o valor de `v2` pode ser tranquilamente ignorado. Se ele pode ser ignorado, eu posso dizer que `v2 == v1`, adicionar essa nova restrição. Assim, tenho que as transições válidas para Autômato Capado são as seguintes:

```
S1(v1) ::= S2, v1, =>
v1 precisa ser do alfabeto de entrada
```

Sabe qual autômato tem exatamente essas características? Isso mesmo, Autômatos Finitos Determinísticos. Com essas 3 limitações, eu limitei o poder computacional de uma Máquina de Turing para um AFD. Inclusive tem o mesmo comportamento de ser não destrutivo com a palavra que está sendo processada, mantém ela intacta no final da leitura.

Siga parte da segunda restrição (no caso, impeça que `v1` possa ser a célula vazia, mas precisa ser um superset do alfabeto de entrada), porém abandonando a primeira e a última restrição, temos algo com poder computacional no mínimo idêntico ao de uma AFD. Porém, agora eu consigo reconhecer palavras do tipo `A^n B^n`. E, como `A^n B^n` não pode ser reconhecido por um AFD, uma máquina de Turing com fita de tamanho fixo tem maior poder de processamento que um AFD.